# OneDrive for Mac crashes

Tags: macos, ms-office, crash, mojave

I have a Macbook pro with the Mojave OS 10.14.1  I have installed Onedrive (two accounts, 1 academic and 1 personal) and they used to work fine for more than a year.  Suddenly, Academic Onedrive (business version), stopped syncing and while it is trying to connect every time crashes.
I tried to make work alone by quitting the personal account but ended with the same result (crashing)
Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Did you try reinstalling it?

Comment: No, not yet....

Comment: Use [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to uninstall first. It will find all those files buried in the system related to the app where a corrupted file might exist.

Comment: Did OneDrive have an uninstaller?  I just installed Backblaze and it came with an uninstaller.

Answer (score 2):

Since OneDrive is available on the Mac App Store, it's far preferable to get it from there going forward. Follow the uninstall instructions for the older app and enjoy a much easier update and reinstall process.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OneDrive-for-Mac-FAQ-3fc4062c-8051-4392-bff1-551e32840cd0

The uninstall is very easy - just install the latest version, then drag it to trash. The 2019 versions also have a nice reset tool and can show very helpful logs should you not be able to fix things from the FAQ:

> **How do I uninstall the OneDrive app?**
>   Just drag the OneDrive app to the Trash.
>
> How do I reset the OneDrive app?

See the link above for the detailed reset instructions if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to uninstall and install again the Bussiness (Academic) version of OneDrive.
For this, I used AppCleaner.